# How to add multiple recipients to mailitem.cc field c#

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, visual-studio-2005, office-2007

Oki, so im working on outlook .msg templates.
Opening them programmatically, inserting values base on what's in my db.

ex. when i want to add multiple reciepients at "To" field, instead of doing as following,

```
   mailitem.To = a + ";" + b + ";" + c;
```

i do whats below, which is simpler, especially when i'm doing it in a loop.

```
   mailitem.Recipients.add("a");
   mailitem.Recipients.add("b");
   mailitem.Recipients.add("c");
```

My problem is, i also want to add multiple recipients at "CC" field and the function above only works for "To" field. How can i add multiple recipients to "CC" field without having to do string manipulation.

normally i would add recipients to cc like so,

```
   mailitem.CC = a + ";" + b + ";" + c;
```

im using interop.outlook and creating an mailitem from template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose If you have two `List` of recipients, then you can do like this.

**Edit**: Included full code.

```
var oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var oMsg = (MailItem) oApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

Recipients oRecips = oMsg.Recipients;
List<string> sTORecipsList = new List<string>();
List<string> sCCRecipsList = new List<string>();

sTORecipsList.Add("ToRecipient1");

sCCRecipsList.Add("CCRecipient1");
sCCRecipsList.Add("CCRecipient2");
sCCRecipsList.Add("CCRecipient3");

Recipients oRecips = oMsg.Recipients;

foreach (string t in sTORecipsList)
{
    Recipient oTORecip = oRecips.Add(t);
    oTORecip.Type = (int) OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
    oTORecip.Resolve();
}

foreach (string t in sCCRecipsList)
{
    Recipient oCCRecip = oRecips.Add(t);
    oCCRecip.Type = (int) OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
    oCCRecip.Resolve();
}

oMsg.HTMLBody = "Test Body";
oMsg.Subject = "Test Subject";
oMsg.Send();
```

Comment: can't get it to work, are you sure it should work with outlook 2007 / office 2007 ?

Comment: @Mana: What was the problem you're facing?

Comment: could you explain this line?
    Recipient oCCRecip = oRecips.Add(p_sUserID);
where or what is p_sUserID doing in .add() ?

Comment: @Mana: Sorry. Forgot to edit that code part. Check the edited code

Comment: thanks, trying it out now, just one thing, how do you reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application ? i mean where do you find it? because im doing as following //Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application and Outlook.Application was same if you are using the statement `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`. Anyway to add,Right click References --> Add Reference --> COM tab --> Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library

Comment: hi again, im having problems with this line:
    oCCRecip.Type = (int) OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
cant find Type oCCRecip.Type

Comment: Do you have this line? `Recipient oCCRecip = oRecips.Add(t);`

Answer (score 3):

Use the Recipients property as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866751.aspx) (look for the second example). you can add a lot of people to the collection and then change the destination type from `to` to `CC`.

Comment: that example is for vba, im programming in c#, and even if i were programming in vba, the CreateItem would not work since im using office2007

Comment: I thought they had the same API. But you know what, I like Ramesh's answer better than mine.