# Including multiple CC's in an Outlook Mail

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, carbon-copy

I have a program that sends and email out to user when they have been added in.

I want the email to cc in multiple members of the IT team, however, I can only get it to CC to one person.

Below is my code:

```
                objMail = CType(objOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)

                ' Set the properties of the email.
                With objMail
                    .Subject = "Website Credentials"
                    .To = "chris.downs@test.com"
                    .CC = "benji@test.com, Alicia@test.com"
                    .Body = "Hi"
                    .Send()
                End With
```

This causes the email not to send at all. I have also attempted the below and this only CC's the last person not both.

```
                ' Set the properties of the email.
                With objMail
                    .Subject = "Website Credentials"
                    .To = "chris.downs@test.com"
                    .CC = "benji@test.com"
                    .CC = "Alicia@test.com"
                    .Body = "Hi"
                    .Send()
                End With
```

Is there a simple way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple recipients to mailitem.cc field c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691888/how-to-add-multiple-recipients-to-mailitem-cc-field-c-sharp)

Comment: @AFriend - Relevant, not necessarily duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook, unlike standard email clients, separates entries on the TO, CC, and BCC lines with `;`, not `,`. Change your CC line to

```
.CC = "benji@test.com; Alicia@test.com"
```

and it should send to both.

Answer (score 4):

Your first try wasnt that bad.
Just replace the comma with a semicolon.
I think it should work like this

```
    .CC = "benji@test.com; Alicia@test.com"
```